# how to change select box value based on saved select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (itemPrice != null) {
        var option = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < itemPrice.d.length; i++) {
            option += '<option value=' + itemPrice.d[i].ListNum + '>' + itemPrice.d[i].ListName + '</option>';
        }

    } else {
        SessioExp(response.statusText);
    }

    tblRow += '<td style="width:20%"><div id="' + d.ItemCode + '"><select class="customSelect" name="dropdown" >' + option + '</select></div></td>';
    $.each(itemLinked, function (k, v) {
        if (d.ItemCode == v.ITEMCODE) {
           //Here set v.PRICELIST TO OPTION VALUE
            if (v.ISLINKED) {
                tblRow += '<td style="width:10%" align="center"><a href="#"><span id="existingData" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="false" style="display: none;"></span></a></td>';
                tblRow += '<td style="width:10%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="chkLinked" checked /></td>';
                flage = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

I want set select box value  when condition true if (d.ItemCode == v.ITEMCODE)

```
tblRow += '<td style="width:20%"><div id="' + d.ItemCode + '"><select class="customSelect" name="dropdown" >' + option + '</select></div></td>';
```

Here we want to show first saved value.

Comment: So.....are you saying that you need to show a pre defined selected option from the dynamically generated options?

Comment: yes i want use pre defined selected option

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your generated options have been appended to the html, you can simply call the JS function `optionID.selected = true`

So for that you will need to define ids to all your options

```
// assuming that all your values are unique
for (var i = 0; i < itemPrice.d.length; i++) {
   option += '<option id=' + itemPrice.d[i].ListNum + ' value=' + itemPrice.d[i].ListNum + '>' + itemPrice.d[i].ListName + '</option>';
}
//pass the option id here
//P.S you can only call this funtion only if the options have been appended to the html
function defineOption(optionID) {
     document.getElementById(optionID).selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Did you first append the html and then call the function?

Comment: yes, and after appending 'blRow += '<td style="width:20%"><div id="' + d.ItemCode + '"><select class="customSelect" name="dropdown" >' + option + '</select></div></td>', I want to change option value to saved value that is v.PRICELIST in if (d.ItemCode == v.ITEMCODE)  condition.

Comment: By append the html i mean create the doms and not keep them in js. Because unless they are present in the doms, the js will not function